# How can I create chart with multiple series in anychart?

Tags: data-visualization, anychart

It is easy to create simple chart using JSON in anychart, but I can't find documentation how to add multiple series (i'm using JSON config). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check it http://docs.anychart.com/7.8.0/Working_with_Data/Data_From_JSON#multiple_series . Anychart has  a good examples.